# Contact name not showing in Notifications when Sms receives

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, title

I am making an app in which when a new SMS receives from known number i.e. if the number is saved in contact list then push notification show. Now the problem is that the notification is not showing display name of contact. It can show message number and message content but not showing display name for that contact.

My code to check if new SMS comes from contact saved is:

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
Uri.encode(number));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
try {
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
      return true;
   }
} 
finally 
{
    if (cur != null)
   cur.close();
}
return false;
}
```

and code for notification alert is:

```
if (contactExists(context, msg_from))
        {

            NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
            notify.setContentTitle(msg_from);
            notify.setContentText(msgBody);
            notify.setAutoCancel(true);
            notify.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notify.setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 2000);
            notify.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            notificationIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intentt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
            notify.setContentIntent(intentt);
            //notify.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 268435456));
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notify.build());

        }
```

now as you see in this line i write "msg_from"

```
notify.setContentTitle(msg_from);
```

this will give me the number from where message come from but if i write this:

```
notify.setContentTitle(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

or other solutions that i found on internet then the notification title displayed will show this string "display_name" and not showing actual name
Please Help!

Here is my all code for that class

```
public class TodoRe extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;

ArrayList<String> keywordslist = new ArrayList<String>();


@SuppressLint({ "DefaultLocale", "InlinedApi" })
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

LinkedHashMap<String, String> contactNumber = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
DBkeyword screenedKeywordDB = new DBkeyword(context);
SQLiteDatabase db = screenedKeywordDB.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cur1 = db.rawQuery(Constants.readScreenedKeywords, null);
cur1.moveToFirst();
while (!cur1.isAfterLast()) 
{
    keywordslist.add(cur1.getString(0));
    cur1.moveToNext();
}

db.close();
DBTable dbtable = new DBTable(context);
SQLiteDatabase dbrsn = dbtable.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur = dbrsn.rawQuery(Constants.readScreenedNumbers, null);
cur.moveToFirst();

while (!cur.isAfterLast()) 
{
  contactNumber.put(cur.getString(0), cur.getString(1));
  cur.moveToNext();
}
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
  Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
  SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
  String msg_from,msgSenderName;
  if (bundle != null) {
    try {
      boolean keywordPresent = false;
      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
        String title= cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        msg_from = Utilities.extractNumbers(msg_from);
        Long dateLong = msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();
        String msgDate = dateLong.toString();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("address", msg_from); 
        values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis()+""); 
        values.put("read", "1"); 
        values.put("type", "1"); 
        values.put("body",msgBody); 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/"); 
        context.getContentResolver().insert(uri,values);

        if (contactExists(context, msg_from))
        {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
            notify.setContentTitle(title);
            notify.setContentText(msgBody);
            notify.setAutoCancel(true);
            notify.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notify.setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 2000);
              notify.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            notificationIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intentt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
            notify.setContentIntent(intentt);
            //notify.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 268435456));
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notify.build());

        }


public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
Uri.encode(number));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
try {
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
      return true;
   }
} 
finally 
{
    if (cur != null)
   cur.close();
}
return false;
}
```

Here is the code now updated one

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
        values.put("address", msg_from); 
        values.put("date", System.currentTimeMillis()+""); 
        values.put("read", "1"); 
        values.put("type", "1"); 
        values.put("body",msgBody); 
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/"); 
        context.getContentResolver().insert(uri,values);
        String title = contactName(context, msg_from);
        String sss=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (contactExists(context, msg_from) && title != null)
        {
            NotificationCompat.Builder notify = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notify.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon);
            notify.setContentTitle(sss);
            notify.setContentText(msgBody);
            notify.setAutoCancel(true);
            notify.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
            notify.setLights(Color.GREEN, 2000, 2000);
            notify.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            notificationIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intentt = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
            notify.setContentIntent(intentt);
            //notify.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 268435456));
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notify.build());

        }

public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
Uri.encode(number));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
try {
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
      return true;
   }
} 
finally 
{
    if (cur != null)
   cur.close();
}
return false;
}

public String contactName(Context context, String number) {
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
Uri.encode(number));
String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
try {
   if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
       return cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME ));
   }
} 
finally 
{
    if (cur != null)
   cur.close();
}
return null;
}
```

Now there are two methods,one to check if exist or not and other to return name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DISPLAY_NAME` constant is the name of the database's table column that holds the contact's display name. It's value is `"display_name"`, which is why you're seeing that in the `Notification`.

You want the value that the `Cursor` has for that column. That is, you want:

```
cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME))
```

---

Change the `contactExists()` method to return a `String` for the display name, instead of a `boolean` that just indicates whether it exists.

```
public String contactExists(Context context, String number) {
    ...

    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME ));
        }
    } 
    finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then, change `title` to be the return from that method, and change the `if` statement to check if `title` is not `null`.

```
String title = contactExists(context, msg_from);

if (title != null) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notify = ...
    ...
}
```

You might also want to change the `contactExists()` method name, since it's now returning the display name.

Comment: i write this line and save it in string name "title" and then i  write notify.setContentTitle(title); but now notification doesnot showing up

Comment: You'll have to edit your question with the changes you've made to the code. I can't tell from your comment where it might be failing.

Comment: Yeah, you're using the wrong `Cursor`. You wanna change the `contactExists()` method to return the display name, instead of just `true` or `false`. Gimme a minute, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok sir lemme check this

Comment: when SMS receives now following error showed up and app force closed

Comment: Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: oh sorry sorry that was my fault i again go through with my code that you suggest and it works like a charm Thankyou so much SIr

Comment: Did you get it? Cool. Yeah, you don't need the `contactExists()` method anymore. Just check that `title` isn't `null`. Glad you got it working. Cheers!